# Parse Gson with Java to get values

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I would like to get value from JSON. I am using Google Gson.

Here is my Json format :

```
{
    "idContact" : 1,
    "message" : "myMessage",
    "date" : "07/03/2016 21:58:38",
    "Client" : {
        "idClient" : 122,
        "lastName" : "LASTNAME",
        "firstName" : "FIRSTNAME",
        "phone" : "060000"
    }
}
```

I can get values from `message` and `date` by using :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
MyClass myClass = gson.fromJson(jsonMessage, MyClass.class);
System.out.println("message: "+smsJson.getMessage());
```

But I can't have values for my Client. When I do `System.out.println("message: "+smsJson.getClient().getId());` I have null pointer exception.

`MyClass` is :

```
public class MyClass {
String message;
String date;
Contact contact;
Client client;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the `MyClass` class.

Comment: I think the issue is **Client** and with capitalization of the first letter. And also make sure if the getter is written properly in your class.

Comment: .. well on the Java side, the name of the field is "client", and in the json it's "Client". It's case sensitive so that is why you get a NPE. Use the `@SerializedName` annotation if you can't fix the json input.

Comment: Oh yes.. The problem is from capitalization...
But now, I get value = 0 but is should be 122. Do you know why ?

Comment: Be sure the field in the `Client` class is named `idClient`.

Comment: It's ok, thanks a lot !!!